# Is there a deterministic algorithm to construct $(n,k)$-universal set of minimum size?

Tags: algorithms, sets, coding-theory

Let $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$, $S$ is a $(n,k)$-universal set if for every subset of indices $I$ of size $k$, projecting $S$ to $I$ yield the $2^k$ binary strings (all the possible strings of $I$). $S$ is of minimum size if there is no other $(n,k)$-universal set $S'$ where $|S'|<|S|$.

is there a known algorithm to construct a $(n,k)$-universal set in general and of (close-to) minimum size in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Such constructions appear in papers of [Seroussi and Bshouty](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~bshouty/MyPapers/Vector%20sets%20for%20exhaustive%20testing%20of%20logic%20circuits/Vector%20sets%20for%20exhaustive%20testing%20of%20logic%20circuits.pdf), [Alon](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/Publications/Explicit%20construction%20of%20exponential%20sized%20families%20of%20k-independent%20sets.pdf), and [Naor and Naor](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/bias.pdf). See [Bshouty](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2012/011/download) for the latest on this topic.